# VSTS Release Definition Variables

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to access environment variables in Visual Studio Team Services through REST API? I have a couple of environments defined with around 50+ variables and during the development phase team adds one or more variables and it becomes hard to spot added variables and propagate it in other environments. The UI is also not very intuitive it shows one table which cannot even be exported to compare.

[image]

Comment: I only learned this recently but in the upper right corner (not shown in your image) there is a little link that you can click to toggle release vs environment variables. When it's in environment mode it shows all variables for all environments side by side. Quite useful actually though not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the variables tab at the release definition, there is a filter at the top right of the editor which will allow you to easily compare variables across environments.

You can export the whole release definition by clicking on the three dots in the left pane which shows list of release definitions and then compare variables in JSON.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it is better, does this have a API which I can pool and get notified if someone adds a variable in a environment and doesn't exists in another?

Comment: @ShijuSamuel This works using the response from the GetReleaseDefinition API, you can write few lines of code parsing json and figuring out the missing variables.

Marina has already mentioned the api in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions#get-a-release-definition) to access your release environment variables:

```
GET https://account.vsrm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/release/definitions/definitionID?$expand=environments&api-version=3.0-preview.1
```

Then you will get variables for different environments, and compare variables or their values as you want.

**Note:** you should add `vsrm` after your `account`.